# Make Pandas find missing values and display them

Tags: python, pandas

I'm still a beginner so don't judge hard. I'm trying to get an idea how to approach this and not to get a full code from you.

I have a database that has the following format and has about 9000 lines

```
Location Supplier  Product Price   
NY         GG-10    70      $5  
NY         GG-10    7A      $4   
NY         GG-10    80      $6  
NY         GG-10    8A      $8
TX         GX-05    70      $1
TX         GX-05    80      $3
TN         CX-01    70      $4
TN         CX-01    7A      $5
```

I have uploaded this dataframe to my pandas project and now trying to figure out how to get python to show what items are missing prices. For example, supplier GG-10 has pricing for all 4 items (70,7A,80,8A). GX-05 only has pricing for 2 items(70,80) but is missing 7A and 8A. CX-01 is missing 80 and 8A. So basically I need a dataframe that would show me what suppliers-product combinations are missing prices. As you probably understand, there are only 4 products - 70, 7A, 80, 8A.

I'd like to write the code myself but if somebody could please give me a hint how to approach this, that would be great! Doing this work manually would take me forever

Updated output. For some reason the .dot is not wrapping the columns into one cell

```
           Product  70 7A 80 8A
Location  Supplier    
  NY       GG-10    1   1  1  1
  TX       GG-05    1   0  1  0 
  TN       CX-01    1   1  0  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `crosstab`, the freq show as 0 mean missing , then we can just using `dot` to combine them into on cell

```
s=pd.crosstab(df.Supplier,df.Product)
s.eq(0).dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1]
Out[669]: 
Supplier
CX-01    80,8A
GG-10          # blank here means nothing missing 
GX-05    7A,8A
dtype: object
```

Update : Update reason see the comment from OP

```
s=pd.crosstab([df.Location ,df.Supplier],df.Product)
s.eq(0).dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1] # here need to assign it back 
s=s.eq(0).dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1] # adding this line 
s
Out[671]: 
Location  Supplier
NY        GG-10            
TN        CX-01       80,8A
TX        GX-05       7A,8A
dtype: object
```

Comment: @alexb feel free to try it with your actual data , if it work , just let me know

Comment: I totally forgot to mention, that while locations change they will have the same suppliers sometimes. for example both TX and NY may have CX-01.

so, I'll need to compare a combination of location-supplier to listed items

Comment: this is an absolute magic! Thank you so much!! I have yet to understand what we did here but I'll pick this code apart to learn it.

Just curious, how would I inverse the result? meaning, how would I show what products do have pricing instead of showing missing ones. Would I need to change eq to 1?

Comment: @alexb yep , you got the point , change to ne(0), in case you have two product (so the freq not always 1 )

Comment: thanks! last question - when I save that to a csv file, the spreadsheet looks a bit different. Instead of saving the way it looks in Jupyter, it creates a column for each product and indicates existence of pricing for each one in 0s and 1s. I assume we used a true/false method? any way to save the dataframe exactly how we see it in python?

Comment: @alexb do it with to_excel .

Comment: for the love of god I can't understand why that same code is no longer showing the output in the same format. This is what it looks like now
                           70  80  7A 8A
NY  GG-10           1   1     1    1
TX  GX-05            1    1   0     0

Comment: @alexb umm  wired would you like show you output in your question ?

Comment: Just added it. It's weird that at first it was showing identically to your output but now it's not. the code is exactly the same

Comment: @alexb you forget to assign it back , Let me update it

Comment: how could I miss that..  I appreciate your patience! Thanks again and Happy New year!

Comment: yes sir, just did. I'm new here so I didn't it was a thing

Answer (score 1):

You can find set difference

```
product = [ '70', '7A', '80', '8A']
df.groupby('Supplier').Product.apply(lambda x: set(product).difference(set(x)))

Supplier
CX-01    {80, 8A}
GG-10          {}
GX-05    {7A, 8A}
```

Comment: I appreciate it!